# Conditional return in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher query:

`MATCH (group_data:Group)-[]->(asset_data:Asset)<-[metadata:MD]-(:RawData) RETURN group_data, asset_data, metadata`

but, in some cases, Asset node is not connected to any Group node. I still want to get in this case the aseet_data and the metadata.

thanks!!

Comment: Use`OPTIONAL MATCH` instead of `MATCH`

Comment: OPTIONAL_MATCH returns the same as the regular MATCH, so if Asset node is not connected to Group node, it will not return. I need the query to return the results from the original query as long with (asset_data:Asset)<-[metadata:MD]-(:RawData)

Answer (score 0):

You can break down the query and use `OPTIONAL MATCH` like this:

```
MATCH (asset_data:Asset)<-[metadata:MD]-(:RawData)
OPTIONAL MATCH (group_data:Group)-[]->(asset_data)
RETURN group_data, asset_data, metadata
```